# What is the correct way to consume a builder struct and return a field

Tags: rust

I have a message struct that has a bytes field that holds bytes that will be send over the wire

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Message {
    bytes:Vec<u8>,
    received:bool,
    read_head:usize,
}
```

In the `Impl` block I have helper functions

```rust
//constructors
impl Message {
/*....*/
    pub fn empty() -> Message {
        Message {
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
    pub fn with_int(mut self, int: i32)->Self {
        self.write_int(int);// has signature  pub fn write_int(&mut self, int: i32)->()
                            // only mutates bytes field
        self
    }
```

followed by a pack function that adds size to the front of the ``Vec` and returns it

```rust
    pub fn pack(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        let size = (self.bytes.len() as u32).to_be_bytes();
        for i in 0..4 {
            self.bytes.insert(i, size[i]);
        }
        self.bytes.as_slice()
    }
}
```

if I use `&mut self` like above
the following code doesnt compile

```rust
#[test]
fn msg_test(){
    let  msg=Message::empty()
        .with_int(42)  
        .with_int(42)
        .pack();
}
```

with error

```
temporary value dropped while borrowed E0716 creates a temporary which is freed while still in use Note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

If I change the signature of `pack` to

```rust
pub fn pack(mut self) -> &[u8]{/*...*/}
```

I get `missing lifetime specifier`
adding lifetimes like

```rust
pub fn pack<'a>(mut self) -> &'a[u8] {
        let size = (self.bytes.len() as u32).to_be_bytes();
        for i in 0..4 {
            self.bytes.insert(i, size[i]);
        }
        self.bytes.as_slice()//ERR: cannot return reference to local data `self.bytes` E0515 returns a reference to data owned by the current function
    }
```

results in another error

My goal is to have a set of functions that I can chain together returning a field from a consumed struct. I would like to avoid cloning/copying the bytes field if possible as it might be as large as few hundred megabytes. It doesn't matter if the struct gets dropped or not. I am not sure what is the way to this in rust as I am very new to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the vector, not a slice:

```rust
pub fn pack(mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
    // ...
    self.bytes
}
```

If your struct defines a custom `drop` function, you can't simply move struct members out, you'll need to replace them first:

```rust
pub fn pack(mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
    // ...
    std::mem::replace(&mut self.bytes, vec![])
}
```

[`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.replace.html) replaces the vector inside the struct with an empty one and returns the original. It doesn't copy its contents.

Borrowed slices need an owner to be alive. In your code, `msg` is a borrowed slice without an owner, that's why it doesn't compile.

Comment: Why not just return it? `pub fn pack(mut self) -> Vec<u8> { self.bytes }`. The function `pack` receives a `mut self`, replacing `self.bytes` with `vec![]` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Sprite I might be wrong but I assumed using `std::mem::replace` lets the struct drop only keeping the field

Comment: Thanks, I added your remarks to the post.